# How is chrome with the "--remote-debugging-port=0" parameter being detected? (Version 111)

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, browser-automation

Running the latest version of chrome or chromium with the "--remote-debugging-port=0" parameter to enable automation through the devtools protocol makes it detectable when trying to login on gmail.

Already tried setting the navigator.webdriver property to false, but this isn't the vector they're using.

This started on the latest update, on version 111 which also changed how headless mode works on the browser (although I'm not using headless here). On older versions, I can automate gmail normally.

To reproduce the issue, simply run the latest version of chrome or chromium with the --remote-debugging-port=0 parameter and try to login manually on gmail.

Comment: Did you set navigator.webdriver before the scripts of the page ran?

Comment: Yes, using Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument